# Error while submitting topology on storm cluster

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I get following error while deploying a topology on storm cluster on supervisor. I am not able to figure out the exact reason as supervisor is able to find the topology but not able to download the code and execute.

```
2018-01-02 12:23:42.409 o.a.s.d.supervisor [WARN] There was a connection problem with nimbus. #error {
 :cause Connection refused
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.RuntimeException
   :message org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
   :at [org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect retryNext TBackoffConnect.java 64]}
  {:type org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException
   :message java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
   :at [org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket open TSocket.java 226]}
  {:type java.net.ConnectException
   :message Connection refused
   :at [java.net.PlainSocketImpl socketConnect PlainSocketImpl.java -2]}]
 :trace
 [[java.net.PlainSocketImpl socketConnect PlainSocketImpl.java -2]
  [java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl doConnect AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java 350]
  [java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl connectToAddress AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java 206]
  [java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl connect AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java 188]
  [java.net.SocksSocketImpl connect SocksSocketImpl.java 392]
  [java.net.Socket connect Socket.java 589]
  [org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TSocket open TSocket.java 221]
  [org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport open TFramedTransport.java 81]
  [org.apache.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin connect SimpleTransportPlugin.java 103]
  [org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect doConnectWithRetry TBackoffConnect.java 53]
  [org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient reconnect ThriftClient.java 99]
  [org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient <init> ThriftClient.java 69]
  [org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient <init> NimbusClient.java 106]
  [org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient getConfiguredClientAs NimbusClient.java 78]
  [org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient getConfiguredClient NimbusClient.java 41]
  [org.apache.storm.blobstore.NimbusBlobStore prepare NimbusBlobStore.java 268]
  [org.apache.storm.utils.Utils getClientBlobStoreForSupervisor Utils.java 468]
  [org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__9394 invoke supervisor.clj 926]
  [clojure.lang.MultiFn invoke MultiFn.java 243]
  [org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__9163$fn__9181 invoke supervisor.clj 579]
  [org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__9163 invoke supervisor.clj 578]
  [org.apache.storm.event$event_manager$fn__8735 invoke event.clj 40]
  [clojure.lang.AFn run AFn.java 22]
  [java.lang.Thread run Thread.java 745]]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I added

storm.local.hostname: **"local.ip.value"**

to storm.yaml